# iPhone UIDatePicker blue highlight doesn't update on new picker row

Tags: iphone, ios, uidatepicker

I am using an UIDatePicker in my application. When the application loads up, the picker updates to todays date and the row is highlighted in Blue as shown:

[image: UIDatePicker]

However, when I change the values in the picker, the Blue highlight does not move along to the newly selected date, here is a screen shot (notice how the old values still hold the blue highlight) :

[image: UIDatePicker highlight not moving]

I am adding the UIDatePicker via IB and connected with `IBOutlet UIDatePicker *picker`

Does anyone know a resolution here?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that you found a bug, as much as you found a "feature."  The highlighting appears to be intended to allow your user to get back to today's date.  If you really don't like the highlighting, you're probably best off implementing your own custom picker.